# How do I get the start index and number of visible items in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview working in virtual mode, in the LargeIcons view.  Retrieves are expensive, so I want to ask for the data for all the visible items.  How do I get the start index and total number of the visible items?

Update: I am aware of the CacheVirtualItems event.  The third-party database we're using takes ~3s to retrieve a single record, but ~4s to retrieve a thousand records, so I have to do them in large blocks.  I need to make sure the visible records are among those we retrieve, so I need to know the start index and total number of the visible items.  If that's not feasible, I'll have to find a workaround (which will probably involve using a DataGridView with a load of image cells to imitate the LargeIcons view) but I would like to do this properly if possible.

Comment: The title of your question and the question in the text body don't read the same.  The title sounds like you want the start index and number of rows, but in the question it reads like you want data for each of the rows which is too different questions.

Comment: It was some time ago, but it was the index and number I needed. As mentioned in the question, I was using a third-party DB, so I wouldn't expect anyone to answer questions on getting the data without more ino on the DB.

Answer (score 3):

THE REAL Answer is :
* get the ScrollViewer of the ListView.
* ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset is the index of first shown item.
* ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight is the number of items shown.

To get the ScrollViewer, you will need a function, 
FindDescendant(FrameworkElement, Type) that will search
 within the childs of the 
ListView. Call it after Window was loaded.

Code in VB.Net and in C# :

```
Public Function FindDescendant(ByVal MyElementToSeek As FrameworkElement, _
                                  ByVal TypeToFind As Type) As FrameworkElement
    If MyElementToSeek Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    If MyElementToSeek.GetType() = TypeToFind Then Return MyElementToSeek
    For i = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyElementToSeek) - 1
        Dim OneChild = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyElementToSeek, i), FrameworkElement)
        Dim Result = FindDescendant(OneChild, TypeToFind)
        If Result IsNot Nothing Then Return Result
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

.

```
public FrameworkElement FindDescendant(FrameworkElement MyElementToSeek, 
                                         Type TypeToFind) 
{
    if (MyElementToSeek == null) return null;
    if (MyElementToSeek.GetType() == TypeToFind) return MyElementToSeek;
    for (i = 0; 
               (i<= (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyElementToSeek) - 1)); i++) 
      {
        object OneChild = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyElementToSeek, i),
                                                         FrameworkElement);
        object Result = FindDescendant(OneChild, TypeToFind);
        if (Result) return Result;
        }
     return null;
    }
}

    ' MyScrollViewer = FindDescendant(MyListView, ScrollViewer)
```

Comment: `FrameworkElement` appears to only be available in WPF. Is there a WinForms equivalent?

Comment: I'd like to add to this answer:

According to MSDN: If CanContentScroll is true, the values of the ExtentHeight, ScrollableHeight, ViewportHeight, and VerticalOffset properties are number of items. If CanContentScroll is false, the values of these properties are Device Independent Pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through subsequent items, checking their visibility until you reach the one that isn't visible. This would give you a count of the visible items.

For example, something like:

```
        for (int index = 0; index < list.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            if (list.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire)))
            {
                // Add to the list to get data.
            }
            else
            {
                // We got them all.
                break;
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure what effect sorting would have on this though.

Comment: This works, but in the "details" view you need to offset the ListView bounds by the height of the column header.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, and I haven't tested this but could you do:

```
private void GetIndexes(ListView vv, out int startidx, out int count)
{
            ListViewItem lvi1 = vv.GetItemAt(vv.ClientRectangle.X+6, vv.ClientRectangle.Y + 6); 
            ListViewItem lvi2 = vv.GetItemAt(vv.ClientRectangle.X+6, vv.ClientRectangle.Bottom-10); 
            startidx = vv.Items.IndexOf(lvi1); 
            int endidx = vv.Items.IndexOf(lvi2);
            if (endidx == -1) endidx = vv.Items.Count;
            count = endidx - startidx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the CacheVirtualItems event? The control will ask for a range of items instead of one-by-one. Tho, if scrolling, it still may ask for only one at a time. But pagedown/up will trigger the cache mechanism.

Comment: does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old .....
Wrong

```
MyScrollViewer = FindDescendant(MyListView, ScrollViewer)
```

Right is:

```
Dim Myscrollviwer As ScrollViewer

Myscrollviwer = FindDescendant(myListView3, GetType(ScrollViewer))
MsgBox(Myscrollviwer.VerticalOffset)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (var t in listView1.Items)
{                        

    var lvitem = listView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(t) as ListViewItem;                   
    if (lvitem == null) continue;
    //lvitem will = null if it is not visible 

    // otherwise do stuff with lvitem such as:
    lvitem.Foreground = Brushes.Green;

}
```

Comment: OP states that his listbox is in virtual mode.  Accessing the Items collection will throw an exception if in virtual mode (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx, last para in Remarks)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
If ListView.Items.Count > 0 Then
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = ListView.TopItem
    If lvi Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim startIndex As Integer = lvi.Index
    Dim lastVisible As Integer = startIndex
    While ListView.Items(lastVisible).Bounds.Bottom < Me.lvRes.Bounds.Bottom
        lastVisible += 1
    End While
    lastVisible -= 1
End If
```

Comment: OP states that his listbox is in virtual mode.  Accessing the Items collection will throw an exception if in virtual mode (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx, last para in Remarks)