# Visible listview items in winforms listview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

How can I get the visible items from a winforms listview?  There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way, and I am reluctant to query items by control.clientrectangle or other hacks similar to the following:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372011/how-do-i-get-the-start-index-and-number-of-visible-items-in-a-listview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372011/how-do-i-get-the-start-index-and-number-of-visible-items-in-a-listview)

When I say visible I mean the items are visible on the screen.

Comment: ListView.GetItemAt() is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate from **ListView.TopItem** and check **ListViewItem.Bounds** property of each item whether it is located within the client area.

[Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) is a freeware component that have also **BottomItem** property, so you can easily go through the visible items with a **for** loop (if both **TopItem** and BottomItem are not **null**):

```
for (int i = betterListView.TopItem.Index; i < betterListView.BottomItem.Index; i++)
{
  // your code here
}
```

You can try this - it have the same interface as ListView and have many improvements over .NET ListView.

Comment: Link is broken; try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ComponentOwl.BetterListViewExpress instead. Comment at that site indicates the software is now a free trial; the Express version may have been discontinued?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample code using GetItemAt**
Looking at @Hans Passants comment I made a stab at actually creating code.

This code gets the top/bottom items. To get a Collection of visible items should be easy by out from Items where index is between index of top/bottom.

For me this worked much better than using Bounds, the bounds of the ListView appeared to have been higher then the visible part.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Finds top/bottom visible items
/// </summary>
public static (ListViewItem, ListViewItem) GetTopBottomVisible(ListView listView)
{
    ListViewItem topItem = listView.TopItem;

    int lstTop = listView.Top;
    int lstHeight = lstTop + listView.Height;
    int lstBottom = lstHeight;

    int step = lstHeight/2;
    int x = listView.Left + listView.Width/2;
    int y = lstTop + step;

    ListViewItem bottomCandidate=null;
    // iterate by interval halving
    while ( step > 0 )
    {
        step /= 2; // halv interval

        ListViewItem itm = listView.GetItemAt(x, y);
        if ( itm == null )
        {
            // below last, move up
            y -= step;
        }
        else if ( itm == bottomCandidate )
        {
            // Moving still in same item, stop here
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // above last, move down, storing candidate
            bottomCandidate = itm;
            y += step;
        }
    }

    return (topItem, bottomCandidate);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are looking for a function that gives you only the visible item list, there is no such thing. You can go foreach item and check if its visible or not.
(If i understood your question right? Please give much clear explanation)

Comment: How is this a valid answer?  There does not appear to be a "Visible" property on ListViewItem.