# Index of visible items in listview during scrolling

Tags: c#, listview, scroll, items

Can you tell me please how can i get index of first visible item in listview during the scrolling. Let say i have 100 items in listview and there are only 5 items visible in window because it is too small, then i start scrolling through items and to be able to see index of first (or any) of those 5 items curently visible in listview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `TopItem` property which returns the first visible item in the control.

Comment: Thanks, but there was raised exception: " Cannot get the top item in LargeIcon, SmallIcon, or Tile view.".

Comment: This property is valid only when listbox is in List or Details mode. Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372011/how-do-i-get-the-start-index-and-number-of-visible-items-in-a-listview), maybe it will help.

Comment: There are image thumbnails in ListView1. While populating the ListView1 i can select particular item in "listView1_SelectedIndexChanged" event to be raised immediately via DoEvents(). Problem is that while thumbnails are being loaded into ListView1 (could take a while due amount of pictures) i am trying to scroll through thumbnails to select particular item. But after i release scroll bar, it jumps onto first item immediately, therefore i can't select for example item with index 50. I have tried to use "EnsureVisible" property but i don't know how can i set its index to chosen particular item.

Answer (score 0):

You could just View mode to List or Details. From this point, you can get the top item, then change it back to your previous View mode, for example LargeIcon:

```
listview1.View = View.List;
ListViewItem topitem = listview1.TopItem;
listview1.View = View.LargeIcon;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public int firstVisible(ListView lv)
    {
        int i = 1;
        try
        {
            while (lv.GetItemRect(i).X != 0) i++;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int rowWidth = i;
        int rowHeight = lv.GetItemRect(i).Y - lv.GetItemRect(0).Y;
        return -((int)lv.GetItemRect(0).Y / rowHeight) * rowWidth;
    }
```

This returns the first visible index of a listview. I have no clue if there is anything that might break it, it works for what I am doing. I've only tested it with LargeIcons. The good thing about it is it doesn't have to go through every item, it just figures it out from the position of the first item.