# Scroll to item in view, but do not scroll to view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, select, scroll

I'm developing a WPF application, containing multiple ListView's. 
Every view has a button, and the user can press it to initiate a function that processes the items in the view. 
The item count is often up in thousands, and can take a couple of minutes to process.

Now, I want the item currently being processed to be selected and scrolled to so the user can get a hunch of how much has been processed. 
This in turn also makes it easy for the user to know what item causes the processing to stop in the event of an error, as it is selected.

To do this I have bound the ListView's SelectedIndex to my ScrollRow property, which i set in my processing function. 
I then scroll to the selected item using the event SelectionChanged, which runs a function that calls ScrollToView on the selected item.

My window contains many views, so there is often a scrollbar on the main window containing the views. 
The problem is that when I call ScrollToView on a row in a view, the main window also scrolls to this view, when the user wants to look on another view further down in the window.

I have looked into setting the scroll position directly, but haven't found any ways to do that.

How do I prevent the window to scroll when a view in the window scrolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the user will like to see a listbox animating itself other a thousand item.
Rather a little info panel on current processing displaying % progress, current item, time...
But but but....  i'm not here to question your design choices :-)
So what you should do is to get the scrollViewer of your listView, and call ScrollToVerticalOffset on it to have the content to scroll without stealing focus.
To find the scrollViewer, you might use my answer in this question :
[How do I get the start index and number of visible items in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372011/how-do-i-get-the-start-index-and-number-of-visible-items-in-a-listview/11193121#11193121)
If you want to go for a more xaml/binding solution, you might expose VerticalOffset using this kind of solution:
http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/how-to-set-wpf-scrollviewer-verticaloffset-and-horizontal-offset/

Comment: Thanks! I now find the ScrollViewer child from the sender of SelectionChanged, and do scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(listView.SelectedIndex) on it. I think you would have another opinion about the design if you saw it in completion :)

Comment: about the design : yes, yes i was kidding you a little, as you noticed  :-) Glad i could help.